# Сохранение изменений ImageView

Tags: java, android

Есть код:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(imageView2);  
imageView.setImageBitmap(null);

ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(imageView2);
imageView.setImageResource(bilder);
```

Первый очищает `ImageView`, второй добавляет изображение.
Как сделать что бы результат сохранялся при выходе из приложения?

Например пользователь очистил `ImageView` и вышел из приложения, как сделать что бы при следующем запуске приложения `ImageView` все так же остался очищенным либо наоборот с добавленным изображением?

Comment: Хранятся, передаются, модифицируются и тд. данные, а не объекты, их содержащие. Это как таскать везде включенный ноутбук с фотографией, чтобы показать ее кому то, вместо флешки, адреса в облаке и тп.

Answer (score 1):

1. При пересоздании активити (после выключения экрана или его поворота) вызывается метод `onCreate()`. В коем полностью создаётся разметка экрана.
2. Значит вам надо именно в этот момент знать пуста картинка или нет. Для этого вам надо получить сохранённую ранее вами же информацию в Bundle активити. Оно передаётся в метод `onCreate()` в качестве аргумента.
3. Таким образом после любых изменений на экране вам надо их сохранить для восстановления. Делается это в методе `onSaveInstanceState()` активити. В вашем случае вы можете сохранить там некий **boolean** флаг, коий и восстановите во 2 пункте.